# Opening CSV file in Excel converts some string fields with numbers(length>20) to scientific notation

Tags: java, excel, opencsv

I am writing a csv file using opencsv. I have a csv field which is of type string and can have only alphanumeric of size 20 . At times the value contains only numbers (i.e) without alphabets.

while opening that file in notepad provides complete value < 66688888888831111111 >, the same file when opened in excel converts the string like :  <6.66888888888311E+019>

Is that the expected behaviour or is there any way to avoid conversion to scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers in Excel are floating point. If you open a CSV containing the value

```
66688888888831111111
```

it will display as

```
6.66889E+19
```

If you format it as text the display does not change.  If you format the cell as Number (preventing the change of display to exponential notation) the result is

```
66688888888831100000
```

This indicates truncation of low-order mantissa bits, and the number of significant digits (14) indicates the internal representation is a 64-bit `long`, as you can see by entering the value in this [online converter](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html).

It gets even worse.  Since CSV is a pure text format and cannot store cell attributes, there's no way to tell Excel to handle that column as text instead of interpreting it as a number.  Even if you put quotes around it in the CSV, Excel will still interpret it as a number.  If you then save the loaded sheet as a CSV you'll get the truncated value.

Comment: I stand corrected, Excel is indeed much worse than Google Sheets at handling writing into CSV.

Importing the following into Sheets and Excel, back out into CSV and back in again yield vastly different results: `="12345612345678901234567890123456","12345612345678901234567890123456"`